# XERO API - JSON for post data was invalid,Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: php

I am using the Xero API, and following the docs but having a problem sending some specific data to this end point: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices#post-invoices

Here is my array in PHP:

```
$customer_details = array(
    'Name' => CompanyName($result["customer"], 'company'),
    'AccountNumber' => '',
    'EmailAddress' => '',
    'Addresses' => (array(
        'AddressType' => 'POBOX',
        //'AddressLine 1,2,3,4' => array($address["line1"], $address["line2"], $address["line3"]),
        'City' => $address["town"],
        'Region' => $address["county"],
        'PostalCode' => $address["postcode"],
    )),
);

$invoice_line_items = array();
$sql2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM invoices_export WHERE export = '' GROUP BY customer;");
while($result2 = $sql2->fetch_array()) {
    $invoice_line_items[]= array(
        'Description' => $result["description"],
        'Quantity' => $result["quantity"],
        'UnitAmount' => $result["unit_price"],
        'AccountCode' => '200',
    );
}

$invoice_data = array(
    'Type' => 'ACCREC',
    'Status' => 'DRAFT',
    'Contact' => $customer_details,
    'LineItems' => $invoice_line_items,
);
```

But the error I receive is this:

```
string(362) "{"Type":"ACCREC","Status":"DRAFT","Contact":{"Name":"ABC Co","AccountNumber":"","EmailAddress":"","Addresses":{"AddressType":"POBOX","City":"City here","Region":"Region here","PostalCode":"AB1 2CD"}},"LineItems":[{"Description":"test","Quantity":"1","UnitAmount":"1","AccountCode":"200"},{"Description":"test","Quantity":"1","UnitAmount":"1","AccountCode":"200"}]}" array(3) { ["data"]=> array(3) { ["ErrorNumber"]=> int(14) ["Type"]=> string(24) "PostDataInvalidException" ["Message"]=> string(660) "JSON for post data was invalid,Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Xero.API.Library.DataContracts.Addresses' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Contact.Addresses.AddressType', line 1, position 132." } ["http_code"]=> int(400) ["error_msg"]=> string(30) "Error : Failed to post invoice" }
```

If I remove the 'Addresses', it works fine. I have added `json_encode` to the Addresses values, but no luck with that either.

Anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: According to the docs, `Addresses` needs to be an array of objects, you provided an object only. (You provided an associative array, to be precise, but encoding as JSON will turn that into an object.) `'Addresses' => (array(` - just wrapping stuff into an additional set of braces does not create an additional array dimension, this needs to be `'Addresses' => array(array(`

Comment: ah nice, that seems to work! thank you

Do you know how I should supply the Address Line 1,2,3,4?

Comment: got it ^ - the keys needed to be AddressLine1, AddressLine2, etc, without spaces

Comment: put your comment as an answer so I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, `Addresses` needs to be an array of objects, you provided an object only. (You provided an associative array, to be precise, but encoding as JSON will turn that into an object.)

`'Addresses' => (array(` - just wrapping stuff into an additional set of braces does not create an additional array dimension, this needs to be `'Addresses' => array(array(`